# W3C CSS Validator shows error on svg rule: "only 0 can be a unit"

Tags: css, validation, svg, w3c-validation

I have an svg that changes its fill and stroke on hover with some transition. I tried using W3C CSS Validator on my css and one of the errors that showed up was this:

```
only 0 can be a unit. You must put a unit after your number : 2
```

But I cannot identify nor understand what the error is. What is wrong in here:

```
svg a:hover circle {
  fill: #ffff00;
  fill-opacity: .5;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
  transition: 200ms;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 200ms;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out
}
```

Comment: I was confused (or maybe lazy) whether to try putting it in either fill-opacity or stroke-width properties.

Comment: Considering only your stroke-width property has a value of 2, I'd assume the error was with stroke-width, not fill-opacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a unit (e.g. px) after the `2` in `stroke-width: 2;`. So like `stroke-width: 2px;`. Zero (`0`) is allowed because it has no value and a unit is irrelevant on it.